# issue with setting up sbt assembly v0.14.2

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-native-packager

I am using sbt v0.13.9 and scala v2.11.7.  I have tried adding the sbt assembly plugin to assembly.sbt as well as plugin.sbt but neither worked:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.2")
```

I have tried adding the sbt native packager to the plugin.sbt but I am getting the same error (copied below):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.1.0-RC1"
```

I have the following resolvers in my build.sbt - I am guessing I need to add a resolver for sbt assembly (even though the docs on that site do not mention anything about it):

```
Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public"),
    Resolver.sbtPluginRepo("releases"),
    Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.2: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.1.0-RC1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.2 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.1.0-RC1 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.2 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13) (/home/test/test-server/plugins.sbt#L4-5)
[warn]        +- com.test:test-server_2.11:1.0.0
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.1.0-RC1 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13) (/home/tets/test-server/plugins.sbt#L6-7)
```

Should I be changing the scala or sbt version to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error messages above, it looks like your plugins.sbt is in your project root directory -- it should be in the ./project/ subdirectory (i.e. /home/tets/test-server/project/ ). Put the reference to sbt-assembly in ./project/assembly.sbt, and the reference to sbt-native-packager in ./project/plugins.sbt

Comment: thanks @ffxtian.  I initially had the assembly.sbt inside my project subdirectory (same for plugins.sbt) - it did not work.  Then I moved it to the project root directory with the same result.  Any other thoughts?  Can you please point to a project on github where this setting actually works (particularly with scala v2.11.7 or earlier) and sbt 0.13.9

Comment: the issue was a typo in my assembly.sbt file.  This will work if the file assembly.sbt is inside the project subdirectory.